# How to make SQL Server database backup and its contents?

Tags: sql-server

How to make backup of my database in SQL Server Management Studio? I can backup the database itself (tables) but I want all the inserted data on those tables backed up too.

Comment: [I mean...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio, (version 2014 in my case) right click the database you want to back up, point the cursor to "Tasks", and when the menu expands, click "Back Up..."

There are several options in here, but I will describe what I typically do. If you have anything in the list below the "Destination" and "Back up to:" labels, click the "Remove" button to the right until the list is empty. Then click "Add". With the "File name:" radio button selected, enter a filename or browse with the ellipsis button, and click "OK". Then just click OK on the original backup dialog with the title "Back Up Database - {database name}".

Comment: But does it include all the data inserted to the selected database ?

Comment: Yes, it includes everything for the database, including data.

Answer (score 0):

1.Right Click on your database, and under “Tasks” choose “Back Up…”

[image: Step-1]

2. You will want to ensure that the “Backup type” is set to “Full” to get a Full backup of your database and highlight the Destination file that is already in the list by clicking on it, and Click “Remove“.

[image: step-2]

3.Now, Click “Add…” to specify where to save the backup file.

[image: step-3]

4.A window will pop up, asking you where to save the backup file. Enter a location of your choice. For this example, we will save it to “C:\Backup\backmeup-Full-041608.bak“

[image: step-4]

You can refer this [link](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/database-backup-ssmse/) for further reference.

Comment: But does it include all the data inserted to the selected database ?

Comment: @RjAlcaraz Yes,it takes a backup of both your schema and data.